# Загрузка и хранение изображений в Java

Tags: java, изображения, разработка-игр, libgdx

У меня есть определенная текстура var1.jpg, и необходимо вывеси ее на экран. Проблема в том, что если при инициализации переменной, хранящей текстуру, указать просто var1.jpg, то программа файл не находит, а если указать полный путь, то все норм.

**Собственно, сам вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы текстура вызывалась, к примеру, из пакета, который будет находиться внутри самой программы? *То есть чтобы в итоге получилось так:* есть программа program.jar, в которой есть 2 пакета - com.start и com.image; при работе программа загружала изображения, лежащие в com.image, а сами классы программы находились в com.start, при этом не важно, в какой директории находится непосредственно program.jar.

Answer (score 1):

Точно не скажу, путь должен быть примерно таким "src\com\image\var1.jpg"